# PHP JSON Web Services

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

**The database does not answer. What's the problem?** 
 *I'm doing with Android.*
*Similar to that in other web services. But they are accurate*

```
<?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        require_once("connect.php");

    if(isset($_POST['id']))
            $gelenid = $_POST['id'];
    else
            $gelenid = $_GET['id'];
    //{
        //$gelenid=$_POST["id"];
    //  $gelenid="36";

        $sql_query="select * from places where ADDED_BY='$id'"; 

        if(!mysql_query($sql_query))
        {
            //  
        }
        else
        {
            $sonucDizisi['basliklar'] = array();

            while($oku=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql_query)))
            {
                $temp['ilan'] = $oku['TITLE'];
                array_push($sonucDizisi['basliklar'], $temp);
            }

            echo json_encode($sonucDizisi);
        }
    //}
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about what is your problem here ?

Comment: I was sending the value to the database. But it does not make any conclusions.Browser comes blank pages.There are data in the database until 7000. Is it caused that?

Comment: ???? Which value were you sending from where? What is 7000?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection and you are using depreciated MySQL Function. If you're getting a blank page, this suggests the SQL Query failed and `!mysql_query($sql_query)` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Since you have nothing to notify you or your app that the query failed, you're getting a blank page.

You also call `$id` versus `$gelenid`, so you're passing a NULL to your query. `$id` is not defined. Here is an example of your code with a Error catch:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $gelenid = $_POST['id'];
} else {
    $gelenid = $_GET['id'];
}
$sql_query = sprintf("select * from places where ADDED_BY='%d'", $gelenid); 

if(!mysql_query($sql_query)){
    $error = array("error" => mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link));
    echo json_encode($error)
} else {
    $sonucDizisi['basliklar'] = array();
    while($oku=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql_query))){
        $temp['ilan'] = $oku['TITLE'];
        array_push($sonucDizisi['basliklar'], $temp);
    }
    echo json_encode($sonucDizisi);
}
?>
```

** EDIT**

From your comments, it sounds like you would like to see an example in MySQLi. Be aware that there are tons of examples at php.net and I will show you one here:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if(isset($_POST['id']))
    $gelenid = $_POST['id'];
else
    $gelenid = $_GET['id'];
}
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    $error = array("Error" => "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    echo json_encode($error);
    exit();
}

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM places WHERE ADDED_BY=?")) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $gelenid);

    /* execute query */
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        $error = array("error" => $stmt->errno . ": " . $stmt->error);
        echo json_encode($error);
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();
        exit();
    }

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $sonucDizisi['basliklar'] = array();

    while ($oku = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $temp['ilan'] = $oku['TITLE'];
        array_push($sonucDizisi['basliklar'], $temp);
    }
    echo json_encode($sonucDizisi);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: use mysql instead of mysql_i  i wanna know the problem corrected?

Comment: I would suggest looking at MySQLi Procedural. It's more like MySQL functions. A lot of the functions can be simply replaced with `mysqli_`, but some require more arguments to be passed. PDO is the other option. Both are good, yet some people prefer one to the other. There are a world of security benefits.

Comment: I just ask you what you exemplified in the above code block?